# Jest unit test 'Function' returns SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at Function (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, testing, leaflet, jestjs, stenciljs

We have a stencil app that calls a wraps leaflet, the style function needs to take a Function as a method parameter, stencil can't do this, so we pass an object and then parse it to a function, anyway this works but trying to test this with Jest is giving us problems.

code

```
public onStylesChange(newVal) {
        this.geoJSONstyles = Function('return ('+newVal+')')(); //      
        if (this.geoJSON) {
            this.geoJSON.setStyle(this.geoJSONstyles);
        }
    }
}
```

test

```
it('Should accept a function parameter', () => {
    cut.onObjChange({test:'object'});
    // expect the cut.geoJSONStyles property to be of type Function.
    expect(typeof cut.geoJSONstyles).toBe('Function');
})
```

returns

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Function (<anonymous>)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Uh, why not just `onObjChange = newObj =>  this.parsedFunction =  () =>newObj` - no real need for `new Function` here.

Comment: Also, that test doesn't match the tested function - where does `cut.geoObj` come from? It's not reference anywhere in the code and it *seems* like calling `onObjChange` is supposed to set the parameter supplied to `cut.geoObj` and instead it creates a function that returns the object when executed and assigns it to the `parsedFunction` property.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that, the test was just there for illustration, don't take it as literal, had to cut down from out production code, quite possibly left stuff out ;)

Comment: Also, I'm really confused what `new Funcion` tries to accomplish. You have a method that creates a new function that returns the object supplied as a parameter to the method but you also execute the function immediately. So it's a really roundabout identity function `x => x`. You can make functions returning dynamic objects in JS anyway - if you need to wrap a parameter in a thunk, it's `x => () => x`, if you need a function to return a function, it's classical currying `a => b => a + b` and so on. I think the `new Function` code is redundant which probably makes this an XY problem.

Comment: Yes I can see how that might be a bit miss leading in the test, we don't need an object back, we need a Function to pass to leaflet, so we take an object, wrap it in a function and return that.
for example on Leaflet's geoJSON.setStyle() call takes a function eg 
function (geoJsonFeature) {
    return {}
} so this is why we need to do it.

Comment: The edit makes no sense `Function()` will create a *new* and *different* empty function - `Function() === Function() //false` - they would be two different objects, same as when you have `{name:"bob"} === {name:"bob"} //false`

Comment: Ok, then what would you use test the response? (was just trying to get something to work)

Comment: It depends on what you are actually trying to test. The test still makes no sense in the code provided, as it tries to check a property not shown. Still, you probably need to rethink some of the structure here - I'd personally have a method that constructs and returns that function (or whatever) then test if 1. it returns stuff 2. the thing returned looks OK. Then I'd have another method that assigns the constructed thing to a property and I'd check if 1. it calls the constructor method and 2. it assigns to the correct property. You can make more in-depth tests for the creation later.

Comment: At any rate, I can't really say without more knowledge of what exactly is supposed to be happening. At this point in time, I can just say it looks like an incorrect approach.

Comment: What we are trying to do is take an object containing style properties, wrap this in a function then call leaflets setStyle function which takes the function as an parameter, what I want to test is, when I call the function with an object, that it wraps it in a function,  ready to call the leaflet setStyle function, is that any clearer?

Comment: OK, so you want to wrap an into a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) which is `x => () => x`. You can assign this to a function and test that, knowing the thunk works. You then have another function that takes an object, wraps it in a thunk and passes it off elsewhere. You test that it calls the function for thunk making and you test that it also calls the function that it passes stuff to. You can mock everything, if you wish to just isolate it to the barebones operations of `toThunk -> setStyle` without bothering what those two actually do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where my head was at last year, but having a break cleared my thinking.

What I needed to do, which was pointed out to me in the comments, so thanks fo rthat, was to check the types, also I could return the function as a string and check that. 
(ignore what the function does, it's only to test the assignment)
so

```
it('Should accept a string function and eval to a function', () => {
    const testString = 'function () {return 0 }'  
    cut.onObjChangetest(String);
    expect(typeof cut.onEachFeature === 'function').toBeTruthy();
    expect(cut.geoJSONstyles.toString()).toBe(testString);
})
```

Works perfectly and the test passes, wooh hooo!
Thanks